# Selecting new level - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table to store players with this schema

```
id_person    name   level   experience
```

And a table that stores level and the points of experience a player need to have to be in such level

```
level   points_experience
```

When someone gets experience, it is summed with the current experience, if the player can reach a new level I will update it.
I can do that with some php code and queries, but is it possible with one query to get the level he/she has reached?

Consider this example

```
level   points_experience
1       100
2       200
3       400
4       900
5       2000
```

If a person has 250 of experience, he's currently in level 2. If he gets 1800 points killing a creature, I'd like a query to tell me it's level 5 that I have to use in update.
Database: mysql

Comment: I don't see why you are storing the `level` on the `person` table. If there is a direct relation between `experience` and  `level`, then storing just the experience should be enough, and you should get the level by joining with that table instead of start constantly updating that value

Comment: Good point. I will think about that. There are more stuff besides this interaction that I might have to change in order to do what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT level
FROM experience_levels                     # put the correct table name
WHERE points_experience < (250+1800)       # put the actual value here
ORDER BY points_experience DESC
LIMIT 1
```

What happens if the user has less than 100 points experience? You should add an extra row with `points_experience = 0` or handle this case from your client code (the query above will not return any row) or make sure it never happens.

If you need the level added to the user information then you can `JOIN` the tables

```
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(l.level, 0) AS level
FROM players p
    LEFT JOIN experience_levels l ON l.points_experience < p.experience
WHERE p.id_person = 123                # put the correct ID here
ORDER BY l.points_experience DESC
LIMIT 1
```

For players having less than 100 points of experience this query should return `0` in the `level` column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's quite simple actually. I have level for zero experience, the question was simplified :)